# IOS login page with flickr API

Tags: flickr

Hi there i'm trying to get the source code for a user to login with their flickr account details or just a "log with flickr" button. is there anyone who can help me with that or where i can get the skeleton code

Comment: Please don't do tag spamming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using the Flickr API, [here](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/).

Note that tag spamming isn't a good thing.